# How to deal with a large dataset when implementing clustering?

Tags: r, machine-learning, correlation, dataset, mixed-type-data

I am working with what I believe is quite a big dataset, with $17$ columns (each corresponds to one variable) and $41714$ rows (each corresponds to one observations).

My goal is to implement clustering algorithms with $16$ of these variables and then check if the clusters created coincide somehow with the categories that are given by the categorical variable I am leaving out of the clusters formation.

I was able to perfom $k-means$ algorithm using only the quantitative variables and also perfomed $k-means$ algorithm using every type of variables (in this case, I coded the qualitative variables accordingly).

**The problems.** Issues started coming up when I tried to implement different methods of clustering (initial results using $k-means$ weren't satisfatory): when trying to compute, for example, $k-medoids$ method, I am given the following error (by RStudio):

> Cannot allocate vector of size $6.5$ Gb.

After some research, I figured this is a RAM memory issue and so my idea to deal with this is to remove some variables from my dataset, which are less correlated with my left out categorical variable.

**How should I do this.** The variable left out is "City" and it is a factor with $9$ levels ($9$ City names). The other $16$ variables are mixed type variables (some are logical/boolean, others are numeric or integers).

How can I determine which variables to remove from the dataset? Is Chi-Squared-Test a good approach to take decisions?

Thanks for any help in advance.